# Gradle build failed to resolve library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, java-websocket

I am working on android (Java) and trying to consume websockets so I thought I would use [this tutorial](https://www.varvet.com/blog/using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/) and they are using dependency `org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0` from [this repo](https://clojars.org/repo/org/java-websocket/java-websocket/) which has now become `1.3.1`.

So I have in my modular `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.1'
    ...
}
```

and in my project / top level `build.gradle` I have

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://clojars.org/repo' }
    }
```

and I am getting error

```
Error:(49, 13) Failed to resolve: org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with lowercase:

compile 'org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.1'

It worked for me.

Edit:

the project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://clojars.org/repo' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://clojars.org/repo' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately the error still appears.

Comment: You have some obvious other problems. Maybe internet connection? Check if gradle isnt set to offline work. Can you add any other dependencies? As I said I just tried it and it worked for me. You can check the url itself to find the JAR file as well, and its there. Nothing seems to be wrong with your code.

Comment: Ha. My gradle was set to offline. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue ,I restarted Android Studio and sync again,it build successfully.